# Why has the generalist badge not been awarded yet

Tags: discussion, badges

The Generalist badge states: Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags

However it has not been awarded yet, and there should be a few people who have met this criterion.  I checked for myself and I have non-wiki answers of 15 total score on 35 of the top 40 tags, and I'm sure @Roger and @Ben also have met the requirements.

Is there something that I am missing here?  If the badge isn't working, we should remove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generalist requires [200 questions in each of the top 40 tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/166936) before it is awarded; the site hasn't yet reached that milestone so Generalist badges just aren't given out yet. This requirement is not listed on the /Badges page because...well I can't really think of a good reason.

I've already [requested this limitation be reduced or removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127689/reduce-or-remove-the-200-questions-restriction-on-generalist-badge) to little effect.

Comment: Each needing 200 seems like a poor choice for smaller sites.

Comment: @JohnGB yeah, it basically makes it a badge for the site, not the users. Few sites have actually gotten enough questions to award that one.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Bens' answer we can calculate when the generalist badge will be awarded

- The 40th tag on UX.SE is [e-commerce](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce) having 101 questions.
- UX.SE is ~ 2½ years old.

If it's a linear trend and if it continues, the generalist badge will be out in the open by fall 2015. By then you will have reached almost **50k** in reputation and earned **14 gold** badges, **80 silver** badges and **224 bronze** badges.

If we want to get there faster, we need to ask more questions containing these top 40 tags.

Comment: Or do things to get more users on who ask questions.